# ImportError: no module named BeautifulSoup or BeautifulSoup4 - Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

On MacOS, I installed homebrew, then installed pip.

Trying to use a Python scraper that uses "BeautifulSoup" package.

Ran: `pip install -r requirements.txt`

requirements.txt includes:

```
BeautifulSoup
ipython
```

BeautifulSoup gives an error, after googling I realized that there is a new version. so I ran:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

seems to have installed correctly. Then I ran the scraping script and I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape.py", line 3, in <module>
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup
```

I tried changing BeautifulSoup to BeautifulSoup4 in the script, but it is the same error.

Anything else I can try?

This is the script I am trying to use: https://github.com/jojurajan/wp-content-scraper

Comment: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Comment: @mamun I get the error from: can't read /var/mail/bs4

Comment: @Sackling How did you end up with `/var/mail` on your modules path?

Comment: That is the error if you run `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` in Terminal directly. This is a Python statement not a bash script.

Comment: Why does a scraper written in 2014 use BS3, which was already dead for over a year by then?

Comment: Actually, looking at the code: I wouldn't trust this scraper very far. It looks like the author just dumped his initial "works for me" version on github and then never maintained it (and may well have never used it again, once he scraped his own old WP site…). It has no error handling, is written for old versions of Python and BeautifulSoup (and requires iPython?!), and says that it only works on Apache-WP sites.

Comment: It probably _is_ a great source of sample code. The whole thing is only a few dozen lines, and most of it should be understandable to even a novice. But I'd just borrow its ideas and write your own bs4 code rather than trying to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup. But I'm still stuck with installing the beautifulsoup package so I would love to look at the script and see if I can change it or understand it but I'm not even there yet. @abarnert I have no idea how I ended up with that.

Comment: Isn't that `requirements.txt` file should have `bs4` instead of `BeautifulSoup`?

Comment: @Sackling What version of Python do you use? If it's 3.x, you should definitely install BS4, read through its tutorial, and then borrow code out of this scraper to write your own once  you understand how BS works. If it's 2.7, you _could_ install BS3 instead… but I'd still install BS4 and so on.

Comment: @beegee No, the code really is using BS3. Just changing the `requirements.txt` won't work. _Maybe_ just changing that plus the `import` line will work (since its use of BS is pretty trivial), but I wouldn't recommend that to someone who doesn't know BS; better to learn the basics of BS4, read the code to learn what it does, and rewrite it.

Comment: @abarnert it is 2.7 but I found a post saying i needed to take ownership of the python folder. After doing so it seems that beautifulsoup is installed.. but I think the old version. When I try to use the new command I get the error I posted below.

Comment: @abarnert I see ! Thanks !

Comment: Well, if you have to take ownership of a project that's using an abandoned and never-finished library off the internet, you're going to have to take ownership of that library off the internet too, so you definitely need to learn how it works. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially because `beautifulsoup4` has a different interface to
its previous versions.

The old version exposes a module named `BeautifulSoup`.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

The new way to import the module in Python would be.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

However, it seems that you are using a scraper written by someone else relying on the old BeautifulSoup. To solve this you have to install the old version.

Maybe you can share the complete `requirements.txt` and we will see what is the version it's using.

Comment: When I run that command I get the error: from: can't read /var/mail/bs4

Answer (score 0):

The code in question was created by me. The scraper uses Python 2.7 and older version of BeautifulSoup. It was a mistake on my part to not mention the Python version and BeautifulSoup version in requirements.txt. Newbie mistakes while releasing code into the wild. :)

I have updated the README to specify about the supported Python version.